# Using quantedas tokens_compound to join multi-word expressions via underscore in a tokens object

Tags: r, quanteda

I have a `tokens` object in words, without punctuation:

| doc | text |
| --- | --- |
| doc1 | 'Mohammed' 'Fisher' 'is' 'a' 'great' 'guy' 'He' 'loves' 'fishing' |
| doc2 | 'M' 'Fisher' 'likes' 'fishing' 'Fishing' 'yay' |

I want to use [`tokens_compound`](https://quanteda.io/reference/tokens_compound.html) on this to join certain [multi-word expressions](https://quanteda.io/articles/pkgdown/examples/phrase.html) via underscore:

| doc | text |
| --- | --- |
| doc1 | 'Mohammed_Fisher' 'is' 'a' 'great' 'guy' 'He' 'loves' 'fishing' |
| doc2 | 'M_Fisher' 'likes' 'fishing' 'Fishing' 'yay' |

Therefore, I defined a list of multi-word expressions I want to join and used [`tokens_compound`](https://quanteda.io/reference/tokens_compound.html):

```
multiword <- c('Mohammed Fisher', 'M Fisher')
comp_toks <- tokens_compound(tokens, pattern = phrase(multiword))
```

This does not work, neither does

`comp_toks <- tokens_compound(tokens, pattern = as.phrase(multiword))`

nor

`comp_toks <- tokens_compound(tokens, multiword)`

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `phrase()` instead of `as.phrase()`.

```
> quanteda::phrase(c('Mohammed Fisher', 'M Fisher'))
[[1]]
[1] "Mohammed" "Fisher"  

[[2]]
[1] "M"      "Fisher"
```

Comment: I'd love it to be that easy, but `phrase()` returns `'phrase.list' is deprecated. Use 'as.phrase' instead.`. And it doesn't work.

Comment: Make sure that you pass a character vector to `phrase()` and and get a list (see the edit). If so `phrase.list()` is not called. I am the developer of the package.

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite familiar with `quanteda`.
Try this:

1. remove `'` from your `text` column
2. define tokens as `toks <- ...`
3. Use `tokens_compound` and
4. apply `kwic` https://quanteda.io/reference/kwic.html

```
library(quanteda)
library(dplyr)

df1 <- df %>% 
    mutate(text = str_remove_all(text, "\\'"))


toks <- tokens(df1$text)

toks_comp <- tokens_compound(toks, pattern = phrase(c("Mohammed Fisher*", "M Fisher*")))
kw_com <- kwic(toks_comp, pattern= c("Mohammed_Fisher*", "M_Fisher*"))
kw_com
```

```
Keyword-in-context with 2 matches.                                                          
 [text1, 1]  | Mohammed_Fisher | is a great guy He        
 [text2, 1]  |    M_Fisher     | likes fishing Fishing yay
```